# In visual c++, how to move a class to it's own file?

Tags: visual-c++, tfs, visual-c++-2017

I have multiple classes within one file and within another class.  I need to pull one of the classes out and put in it's own file.  I tried the right click:  "Add class" option... but get the ERROR "Class 'xxx' is either invalid or already implemented in the selected source file."  If I try a different name it works... but I need the same name as before.

Comment: Is Michael's answer helpful? any update?

Answer (score 2):

Make a new file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - the simplest solution